# Sonata Admin redirect from preRemove

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have a Entity Group that has an ArrayCollection of Members.

Now I count my Members in `preRemove` of Member and Remove the Group, if the count is zero.

If I now remove all members from the group in Sonata Admin and click "Save", the Group was removed, but Sonata Admin crashs, because the group doesnot exists any more.

Is there a way to redirect to the List when I delete the group on saving?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without the code but the answer should be in your controller. After testing if the group still exists:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_list_route'));
```